# How to deal with account scam and fraud?

Tags: banking, bank-account, scams, mistakes

I gave someone my account information for my bank account because they said they could help me financially. They put $820 in my account and said I could keep some if I sent it to this guy. I never sent it and my account was disabled. I did not know this guy was a scammer. I should’ve known better not to give any information out.

The bank called me and said it was all canceled and I cannot bank with them anymore because my account was shared to a third party. They said it was because of money laundering and I had no clue. I’m a broke college kid needing money to pay rent and tuition. I’ve never been in any legal trouble but I’m still scared.

How do I get out of this mess?

Comment: Did you give them passwords? Was money taken out of your account?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do scammers retract money, while you can’t?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/107003/how-do-scammers-retract-money-while-you-can-t)

Comment: There is a possibility that you just dodge a fraud.  You should contact the bank and file a fraud report to the police so this doesn't jeopardize your future credit record.

Comment: I find the part about "the bank said I couldn't bank with them anymore because my account info was shared with a third party". If they mean, you told someone else your account number, people do that all the time for legitimate transactions. You have to do give others your account number any time you buy something. If they meant "you gave someone else your user id and password" ... how would they know? It's possible that this "call from the bank" is legitimate, but it sounds suspicious. I seriously wonder if it's not part of the scam.

Answer (score 9):

You are in trouble, but possibly not too much if you act properly now.

First change any passwords that you gave out. Do it now. Don't read to the end of the answer do it now.

Then call your bank, on a number you know is valid for them, not any number you were given after this communication, and not the number that called you. Tell them exactly what happened. Ask what you should do. Cooperate with them.

Next you might call a fraud prevention office, or the police, and do the same.

If any money was taken from your account you are going to be responsible for at, and if your account went overdrawn you are responsible for paying it back.

Finally resolve to never ever give your bank details to anyone.

Comment: "*Finally resolve to never ever give your bank details to anyone.*"  Except when writing a check, or filling out a web page to have "them" draft an e-check against your account...

Comment: @RonJohn Living in the UK, I haven't written a cheque, or even had a cheque book, for about 30 years now. During that time I have probably *received* about one cheque every 5 years, and none of them were from unknown private individuals. But if you live in a country where retail banks and their customers still like using 19th century methods for financial transactions (and the 19th century levels of security that go with them) maybe you don't have an alternative.

Comment: @alephzero I can't find it at the moment, but about a month ago someone having questions about a UK bank account disclosed some pretty horrid things about your banking system that make me very glad I use this so-called antique system.

Comment: *"never ever give your bank details to anyone"* So how would OP receive legitimate bank transfers?

Comment: Good answer overall.  I would only add that OP might want to contact a lawyer *before* contacting the police.  If there's even a slight chance he's about to get caught up in some kind of money laundering shenanigans, he ought to have representation to guide him.